# Responsive StaticBox?

Tags: python, wxpython

*I'd like to create some kind of log box to stream the console output of a python application.*

For a nicer appeareance within the UI I'd like to throw the `TextCtrl` into a `StaticBox` and ideally expand it when the user resizes the main frame. I've already tried adding a `GridBagSizer` which allows using `AddGrowableCol(index)` and `AddGrowableRow(index)` methods. However making the row 'growable' has no effect and it's *only working horizontally* at the moment:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):    
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
            size=(450, 350))

        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()     

    def InitUI(self):

        self.main_sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)

        # Create the grouping box and sizer for the outline
        self.box = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, "Logging")
        self.bsizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.box, wx.VERTICAL)

        # Create the sizer and place controls within box
        self.gbs = wx.GridBagSizer(5,5)

        self.log_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(-1, 200), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.VSCROLL)
        self.gbs.Add(self.log_ctrl, (0,0), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=10)

        # Place the control inside group box
        self.bsizer.Add(self.gbs, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.gbs.AddGrowableCol(0)

        # Adding to the main sizer
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.bsizer, pos=(0, 0), span=(1, 30), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.BOTTOM)
        self.main_sizer.AddGrowableCol(0)

        # Place the static group box sizer within the border frame
        # Creating a border that the static box will sit inside
        self.border = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.border.Add(self.main_sizer, 1000, wx.ALL, 15)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.border)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title="Example")
    app.MainLoop()
```

**Question:** Is there any clever way of adding a `wx.TextCtrl` element to a `wx.StaticBox` in order to fill the main window *vertical* as well as *horizontal* when expanding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

```
--- original.py 2016-11-24 08:20:56.958686427 +0100
+++ modified.py 2016-11-24 08:21:53.879980674 +0100
@@ -24,21 +24,23 @@
         # Create the sizer and place controls within box
         self.gbs = wx.GridBagSizer(5,5)

-        self.log_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(-1, 200), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.VSCROLL)
+        self.log_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.box, size=(-1, 200), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.VSCROLL)
         self.gbs.Add(self.log_ctrl, (0,0), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=10)

         # Place the control inside group box
-        self.bsizer.Add(self.gbs, flag=wx.EXPAND)
+        self.bsizer.Add(self.gbs, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
         self.gbs.AddGrowableCol(0)
+        self.gbs.AddGrowableRow(0)

         # Adding to the main sizer
         self.main_sizer.Add(self.bsizer, pos=(0, 0), span=(1, 30), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.BOTTOM)
         self.main_sizer.AddGrowableCol(0)
+        self.main_sizer.AddGrowableRow(0)

         # Place the static group box sizer within the border frame
         # Creating a border that the static box will sit inside
         self.border = wx.BoxSizer()
-        self.border.Add(self.main_sizer, 1000, wx.ALL, 15)
+        self.border.Add(self.main_sizer, 1000, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 15)
         self.SetSizerAndFit(self.border)
```

- Firstly, you forgot to do the AddGrowableRow, that's obvious.
- Secondly, self.gbs must have the proportion=1 (or more) otherwise it will not grow.
- Finally, your main sizer does not expand within the border.

Also, I have made the self.box the parent of the self.log_ctrl, which is supposed to be the right way since wx 2.9.1.

In your example, the GridBagSizers are completely unnecessary:

```
    def InitUI(self):
        # Create the grouping box and sizer for the outline
        self.box = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, "Logging")
        self.bsizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.box, wx.VERTICAL)

        self.log_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.box, size=(-1, 200), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.VSCROLL)
        self.bsizer.Add(self.log_ctrl, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=10)

        # Place the static group box sizer within the border frame
        # Creating a border that the static box will sit inside
        self.border = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.border.Add(self.bsizer, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=15)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.border)
```